# Linux hangs after a few minutes of use but Windows runs fine

Tags: linux, multi-boot, freeze, kernel

Here's the issue I've been facing within the last few weeks, I've tried numerous fixes and none seemed to work.

I have recently bought a Gigabyte GA-970A-UD3P rev.1 motherboard and things began after I started using it. So when I'm under Linux, the PC just freezes after a good few minutes, no matter what I do.
However, when I'm in Windows (10 to be specific) everything works fine. I can game, render videos, and basically everything, no issues at all. This makes me think that there are no hardware issues.

I'm currently running Manjaro (which is based on Arch Linux) but tried multiple distros like Fedora and Solus and had the same problem. I'm currently using GRUB EFI as a bootloader, and have *iommu=pt* and *amd_iommu=fullflush* as kernel options, this made AMD-VI errors from dmesg disappear. I have IOMMU, EHCI and XHCI handoff enabled in BIOS.

So after a few minutes (sometimes it can even last an hour) my system crashes and not even Magic SysRq hotkeys work, so I'm assuming there's a kernel panic happening.

Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: It reminds me of an old story, where there was once a computer which was running 100% fine except for using Word. Using load-hungry applications, gaming, surfing, etc, etc... But as soon as Word was started it just freezed. Turned out that a smaaaaall part of the processor was damaged. No applications were using it EXCEPT for Word. Maybe you got a some kind of similar problem, with the hardware part faulting.

Comment: you may get more attention on this if you add the "dual-boot" tag too

Comment: @Evengard I've tried running a program called _stress_ under Linux but didn't manage to trigger the issue.

LevenTech thank you, I've added it!